# Selenium Stale Element driver.get(url) inside Loop

Tags: python, selenium

I desire to iterate thru a set of URLs using Selenium. From time to time I get `'element is not attached to the page document'`. Thus after reading a couple of other questions indicated that it's because I am changing the page that is looking at. But I am not satisfied with that argument since:

```
for url in urlList:

   driver.get(url)

   WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div')))
   #^ WebDriverWait shall had taken care of it  

   myString = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div').get_attribute("innerHTML")
   # ^ Error occurs here

   # Then I call this function to go thru other elements given other conditions not shown
   if myString:
      getMoreElements(driver)
```

**But** if I add a delay like this:

```
for url in urlList:
   driver.get(url)
   time.sleep(5) # <<< IT WORKS, BUT WHY?
   element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div')))

   myString = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div').get_attribute("innerHTML") # Error occured here
```

I feel I am hiding the problem by adding the delay right there. I have `implicity_wait` set to 30s and `set_page_load_timeout` to 90s, that would had been sufficient. So, why am I still facing to add what looks like useless time.sleep?

Comment: I can't fully answer your question, however I've had this happen to me multiple times when doing loops with selenium. Adding a `time.sleep()` fixed it and I never had an error since. It may be hiding an issue, but it does work. If I would guess, I'd say Python gets to that point faster than what selenium can process, and the page "changes" after the `find_element` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the xpath: //div/div manually in dev tool to see how many div will be found on the page?  I thinks there should be many.  So your below explicity wait code can very easy to satisfied, maybe no more than 1 second, selenium can find such one div after browser.get() and your wait end.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div/div')))
```

Consider following possiblity: 
Due to your above explicity wait issue, the page loading not complete, more and more //div/div are rendering to page, at this time point,  you ask selenium to find such one div and to interact with it.

Think about the possiblity of the first found div by selenium won't be deleted or moved to another DOM node.

What do you think the rate of above possiblity will be high or low? I think it's very hight, because div is very common tag in nowdays web page and you use such a relaxed xpath which lead to so many matched div will be found, and each one of them is possible to cause the 'Element Stale' issue

To resolve your issue, please use more strict locator to wait some special element, rather than such hasty xpath which result in finding very common and many exist element.

Comment: Tried the specific instance of the string, but same result unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try to wait the last element on the page, If there is no luck, even you tried vary element/locator in your wait, you have to consider to use combination: explicity wait and sleep(sleep time should as min as possible)

Answer (score 0):

What you observe as **`element is not attached to the page document`** is pretty much possible.

### Analysis:

In your code, while iterating over the `urlList`, we are opening an `url` then waiting for the `WebElement` with `XPATH` as `//div/div` with **`ExpectedConditions`** clause set to **`presence_of_element_located`** which does not necessarily mean that the element is **visible** or **clickable**.

Hence, next when you try to `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div').get_attribute("innerHTML")` the reference of previous search/find_element is not found.

### Solution:

The solution to your question would be to change the **`ExpectedConditions`** clause from **`presence_of_element_located`** to **`element_to_be_clickable`** which checks that element is **visible** and **enabled** such that you can even click it.

### Code Block:

Your optimized code block may look like:

```
for url in urlList:

   driver.get(url)

   WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div/div')))
   myString = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

### Your other solution:

Your other solution works because you are trying to covering up Selenium's work through `time.sleep(5)` which is not a part of best practices.

Comment: Tried with the specific Xpath and element_to_be_clickable, but still gives me the error if remove the time.sleep.